# Reading MPS file for linear programming and reconstructing the Optimization model

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab, sensitivity-analysis

Are you aware of any tutorial that can help me learn on how to reconstruct the objective function and constraints from a MPS file once it's loaded in MATLAB. I can load the mps file given to me and solve using lpsolve. But I would like to run a sensitivity test by modifying the RHS of a certain constraint. Therefore, it would be helpful if I could reconstruct the constraints from the MPS file.

Comment: Can't you query/modify the RHS value from whichever solver you are using directly? The MPS format is described [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/mps-format.htm). Be aware, MPS was not intended to be read by humans, so making modifications to such files is not user-friendly.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to read the MPS file and write the model out as a LP file again. LP files are non-standard (i.e. you cannot take a CPLEX LP file and give it to Gurobi), however they are human readable and you can then look at them.

Comment: Thank you, would be able to tell how to output CPLEX LP file from within MATLAB?

Comment: I work for Gurobi, so I'd suggest that you use that :) For Gurobi, you can use this: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/matlab_grb_write.html